# Python scripts not running properly from terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I have simple .py files that run fine in my IDE (IDLE), however when I execute from terminal it just gets weird.

I have a folder with a dozen or so .py scripts. I change the directory, then execute `python3 script.py` from terminal but it runs a completely different script. It's very odd. And it's always the same script that is run. They are all independent scripts and don't import anything from each other.

I executed `cat python3 script.py` and it looks exactly as it should. Is there something wrong with my Python installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Some Solutions:
1: Double Check if Python is included in the System Environment.

2: Run the command from a console to directly check and upgrade the pip;

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

in case you have different version of Python Installed

> python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

3: You can locate your Script with Python by creating .bat file for your script and then just double click the bat file to run your script from any directory after locating properly.

4: Check if the script need any requirements to run in console without IDE.

Comment: Thanks! 1: When I run ```printenv```, this is the path: ```PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin``` 
  
2: pip is already up to date. 

3: Working on this...

4: Unlikely, as I can run the script just fine when it's in its own folder; it's just when it's in a folder with a bunch of scripts it runs the wrong one and acts up.

Comment: @Andrew Possible it has some conflicts with other scripts

Comment: Thanks @Arnold-Baba, that's the issue. I did in fact have a script in the folder named the same as something in the standard library I was importing. So that was causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Python did you check the box that said "Add Python to Path" (see screenshot below)[image: Add to PATH]
If not, go Python setup, click on "Modify" and the click "Next". There check the box that says "Add Python to environment variables" and press "Install".  [image: Modify][image: Next][image: Add to path]

Comment: Thanks, I'm on a Mac - but still helpful. I'm able to run scripts from command(terminal) just fine when they are isolated in their own folder, but it messes up when I try to run them from a folder with many scripts. Do you think this is still the issue?

Comment: Im a Windows user so I sadly won't be able to help much more, but this issue seems really odd...